# Which propagation to use in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have two different process ( A and B), and A has to start after B, B must not join the A's transaction, B has to wait until A finish its commit.

what propagation should i use ?

Now it is like :

```
@Transactional
A()
```

and

```
@Transactional
B()
```

Now i use it defult @Transactional, and its not work properly. I think i should use **PROPAGATION**.

I hope the question is clear. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `B()` in its transactional context calling `A()`, then `A()` should use `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation to has its own independent transaction.
[image]

According to spring framework's [Data Access Section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-propagation):

> PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW, in contrast to PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, uses a
>   completely independent transaction for each affected transaction
>   scope. In that case, the underlying physical transactions are
>   different and hence can commit or roll back independently, with an
>   outer transaction not affected by an inner transaction’s rollback
>   status.

Comment: if i use requires_new for A(),it has own its transaction OK, but B() has to start when A() finish its commit, in this case, does it work that way ? Does B() wait A()'s commit?

Comment: If `B()` is calling `A()` in a synchronous fashion, yes it'll wait for `A()`. Otherwise, calling `A()` spawns a thread and returns immediately.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This photo pretty much tells you why you should use REQUIRES_NEW. What you want is invocation always occurs in a new transaction(TX) context.

Note however: Actual transaction suspension will not work on out-of-box on all transaction managers. If you are using `JtaTransactionManager`, you need `javax.transaction.TransactionManager` to be made available to it.

Comment: Ok i get why i have to use REQUIRES_NEW, but my concern is B() has to start after A(), can REQUIRES_NEW does this ?

Comment: yes. it should work as long as you write your transaction properly. You can also use `timeout` attribute in your `@Transactional` to timeout B() for certain milliseconds.